# Create data frame using an object name and p value from var.test

Tags: r

I performed `var.test` on multiple comparisons, for example:

```
dog1cat1 -> var.test(df$dog1,df$cat1)
dog2cat1 -> var.test(df$dog2, df$cat1)
dog2cat2 -> var.test(df$dog2, df$cat2)
```

If I call `dog1cat1$p.value` it will return the desired p-value
I am trying to take the names of test results (e.g. `dog1cat1`) and create a data frame with that tests associated p-value. I am ultimately trying to perform a Bonferroni correction on the p-values. Perhaps I am taking the wrong approach. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to flip your assignment arrows. Then you can put each value into a `data.frame` using `data.frame(p_values = c(dog1cat1,dog2cat1,dog2cat2))`. Then use `stats::p.adjust()` to adjust for multiple comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I get the following warning message when I used ```data.frame``` . Warning message:
In (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

Comment: can you post some data so I can run the code and help further?